# error in vlookup using vba

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am getting error with the following code. The error is showing in last line.Here TargetColNO is 37

```
           Sub lookup1()
           '
           ' lookup1 Macro
           '

           Dim ColIndex As String
           Dim par As String
           Dim Lookup_Range As Range
           Dim sal As Integer
           ColIndex = "C" & TargetColNo
           'Range("O2").Select
           Cells(3, LastCol + 1).Select
           ColName = ColumnLetter(TargetColNo)
           par = "$" & ColName
           'Set Lookup_Range = Range("[NBH_MPP_20161104]NBH!$A:par")
           'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C1,[NBH_MPP_20161104.xls]NBH!C1:ColName,TargetColNo,0)"
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A3,[NBH_MPP_20161104.xls]NBH!$A:par,TargetColNo,0)"
```

Comment: I would guess that you are gonna need quotes around TargetColNo, or " &  TargetColNo & " if it is a variable.

Comment: @Utkarsh Jain try the code in my answer below and let me know if it's working for you

Answer (score 0):

As `TargetColNo` and also `par` are variables, take them outside the double quote, so modify your last line from:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A3,[NBH_MPP_20161104.xls]NBH!$A:par,TargetColNo,0)"
```

To:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A3,[NBH_MPP_20161104.xls]NBH!$A:" & par & "," & TargetColNo & ",0)"
```

**Edit 1**: it is better to avoid using `Select`, and since in your formula you are not using the `R1C1` structure, you can replace the last couple of lines with:

```
Cells(3, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A3,[NBH_MPP_20161104.xls]NBH!$A:" & par & "," & TargetColNo & ",0)"
```